# Adding directive to TabStrip content in Kendo UI/Angular

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I'm coding a Kendo/Angular program that allows users to add tabs to a TabStrip dynamically. This works fine, however I need to include in the tab content an Angular directive, like so:

```
$scope.tabStrip.append(
    [{
        text: "Tab Title",
        content: "<div my-directive></div>"
    }]
 );
```

This does not work as Angular is not aware of the new content. Is including a directive in the content feasible?

Comment: you need to `$compile` that DOM from somewhere..may be `dataBound`/`dataBinding` event of kendo grid would be sufficient..